# Google People API as a Worker/CLI

Tags: python, google-people-api

I'm trying to use Google People API as a python worker (with celery) so this is not a webapp (I'm using the python libraries suggested in their documentation (google-api-python-client, google-auth-httplib2 and google-auth-oauthlib).

So I'd like to use the API keys to access to the API and I can not find any documentation about using in this way and what limitations will have or anything.

I didn't find anyone asking this question before.

Comment: are you using a library or calling the API using HTTP requests?

Comment: Yes, I'm using google-api-python-client, google-auth-httplib2 and google-auth-oauthlib. I edited my post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you're calling the APIs. I advise to use the library for Google APIs.

It seems that the People API is not listed in the APIs available through the Google Cloud APIs [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#libraries).
**NOTE:** you should use that library if the API in question is available there.

The `google-api-python-client` has a description on how to use API keys [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/api-keys.md), but to put it simply, build the service object using the key.

```py
service = build('people', 'v1', developerKey='YOUR_API_KEY_HERE')
```

If you're calling the People API using fe. the requests library (eg. basic normal HTTP call) then just append `key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE` to the URL for the request, as per documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#APIKey).

### **NOTE**

If you're trying to access private data, you simply cannot do this with an API key. (Otherwise you would be able to harvest all contact emails from fe.  Sundar Pichai). You need the consent (and therefore need to use OAuth2.0) to access private data...

Comment: I see, thanks. it returns this message: "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. "

Comment: It seems that for the People API some endpoints accept the API key, but others do not. If you get that response, that means you have to use OAuth2.0. Reading [the auth page](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#APIKey) for the People API, the distinction is whether or not you're calling private data. Makes sense if you think about it, and there's no way around it besides using OAuth2.0